# Best practice if user doesnt have the right ROLE to acces a link

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.3

I'm using annotations for managing security access to my controller, ex :

```
/**
* @Route("/backoffice", name="app.backoffice")
* @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN') or has_role('ROLE_BACKOFFICE')")
*/
public function someControllerAction(Request $request){

}
```

I would like to know how to manage, when a user arrived on this link, but doesn't have one of the roles defined.
What are the best practice ?
Redirection ?
Just display an error message ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the better way to manage It is to redirect to a specific `403` page with a message that user doesn't have the permission to view that resource.

You need to create a `403` page, for It and show a message to tell the user that it doesn't have the permission to view the page